# PBIS ERROR: No credentials found for connection to server when trying to authenticate user

Tags: windows, ubuntu, active-directory, ssh, login

Currently, we are trying to link our new Active Directory system to our old Linux Servers (as we are moving away from LDAP). We have decided to use PBIS for this process and it has worked mostly well so far.

However, we are now running into an issue when we try and authenticate as a user. Every time we get the following:

```
rpc.gssd[331]: ERROR: No credentials found for connection to server ad.test.in
```

We can enumerate users on the linux server and AD shows the device. There are no SSH issues between clients and the Windows Server itself, however, you cannot SSH between the Windows Server and linux server. Password authentication is enabled in sshd_config.

Has anyone run into this before? The only other solutions I can seem to find involve kerberos, which isn't being used.

Comment: AD is built on both Kerberos and LDAP.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, but PBIS doesn't require the installation of kerberos